# Постоянное обновление adapter'a

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть Adapter в котором в каждом item есть картинка, которая должна постоянно вращаться в зависимости от положения сенсора на устройстве.  Положение картинки в item я меняю с помощью обновления адаптера, т.е. таким образом:

```
private SensorEventListener eventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {         
        adapter.angle = event.values[0];
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

В зависимости от угла уже вращаю картинку. Это работает, но из-за того, что постоянно обновляется адаптер очень много раз приходится нажимать на item, чтобы сработал setOnItemClickListener. Есть у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь мысли как решить это?

Comment: я бы проверял, если угол не поменялся сильно (я думаю, что 2-3 градуса никто не увидит), то и не делать обновление.


    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {         
        if (Math.abs((adapter.angle - event.values[0] + 360) % 360) > 3) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

Comment: попробовал, не помогает, если вертеть устройство - адаптер обновляется и setOnItemClickListener не срабатывает.

Comment: а как Вы умеете быстро крутить девайс и жать кнопку?

Но можно ещё добавить фильтрацию - обновлять только каждые пол секунды.

Для этого запоминайте время последнего обновления и сравнивайте его с текущим. Если время прошло мало то ничего не обновляем.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` для всего списка, ради изменения 1 строки?

Сначала чекаем `getFirstVisiblePosition()` и `getLastVisiblePosition()`, если все норм, то берём `View` с помощью `getChildAt(int index)` и меняем вьюху. Тогда не будет полной перерисовки всего списка.

Comment: А вот это плохое решение. Очень плохое и печальное.

Comment: @KoVadim ну да, лучше же полностью обновлять весь адаптер

Comment: @KoVadim почему?

Comment: public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {
            int last = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i < last; i++) {
                View itemView = absListView.getChildAt(i - firstVisibleItem);
                //update itemView
            }
        }

Comment: Сниппет. 
ps не знаю как оформлять код в комментариях

Comment: просто подобавляйте перед каждой строкой кода по 4 пробела.

Изменять listView в обход адаптера чревато различными непонятными багами.

Comment: В том сниппете можно изменять только View самого айтема. Даже Рома Нюрик советовал такое дело. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9987616/1979290

Comment: Видимо, ответа не дождёмся.